# Magento Extension how to deploy in production using Git

Tags: git, magento

I've been developing Magento in my local and i am using git to push my codes.

Now i want to deploy my Magento app in our live server.
Of course because i am using git, i want to git pull my codes in server and tweak some db configurations. So let assume everything works.

When i add new features or update my codes, i code in my local and just git push in my local and just git pull in live server to get the updated codes.

Now i am wondering, what if i install new Magento Extension to my local?
I know there are new files added to my magento codes, so all i have to do is commit and push again.

But how about the database? Im sure there are database updates when installing new extension. I cannot commit and push the database in git.

So how do you handle deploying installed extensions in your local to your live server?

I have not tried anything so far but would love to hear your experiences guys.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento extensions come with their own sql scripts which will execute on the DB if the module is found to be active, but the necessary elements are not present in the database.

These scripts can be found in app/code/local/APP_COMPANY/APP_NAME/sql/APP_NAME_setup/mysql-install-VERSION

It could sit in the /community/ folder rather than the /local/ folder depending on what the module's creators did.

I use git for magento versioning including adding new modules, so you'll be absolutely fine.

Best
Tom

Comment: thats great. i will check test this out and will tag your answer as correct if i am successful with it.. thanks buddy

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I just have to clear the cache via System>Cache Management and select all, then click Flush Magento Cache.